# becomeFirstResponder not showing from viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload, becomefirstresponder

Here I have a simple example. im calling `FirstResponder` in `viewDidLoad`. But accessory view only shows up after tapping the screen. Why isn't it showing from the start?

```
class TestViewController: MainPageViewController {

    private let accessoryView = UIView() //TextInputView() // MessageInputAccessoryView()

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
        return accessoryView
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { return true }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        accessoryView.backgroundColor = .red
        accessoryView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50)
        self.becomeFirstResponder()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappo))
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        tappo()
    }


    func tappo() {
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
    }


}
```

Comment: `accessoryView.becomeFirstResponder()` instead of `self.becomeFirstResponder()`?

Comment: @Larme Nope. ;/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewWillAppear` is a better place to put the `becomesFirstResponder`. Try that.

Comment: So I've tried this with my current project and it woudn't work. But tried creating a sample one, and it does.. I'm using page view controller and inside it one of the pages should become first responder but something must be overriding it... Oh well..

Answer (score 2):

So something was resigning my first responder (as I was using `UIPageViewController`). So I've added this to my `UIViewControler` :

```
override var canResignFirstResponder: Bool { return false }
```

That's it. Cheers!